# Nunit Test failing to compile in appharbor environment

Tags: unit-testing, build, nunit, appharbor

Seems like I may be missing to set some enviornment variable in my [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) environment.
My test folder cannot find reference to the nunit framework. I am using NUnit 2.5.9.

Part of the build output is pasted below. Any ideas what am I missing?

```
Primary reference "nunit.framework".
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "nunit.framework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\temp\oyiirwgf.sjw\input\JeeneeTest\JeeneeTest.csproj]
          For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
          Considered "..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.9\bin\net-2.0\framework\nunit.framework.dll", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\nunit.framework.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\nunit.framework.exe", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.0,AssemblyFoldersEx}".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We (AppHarbor) recommend you use the [NuGet Nunit package](http://nuget.org/packages/nunit). You can either commit the `/packages` folder along with your code or use [NuGet package restore](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/2/06/use-nuget-package-restore-to-avoid-pushing-packages-to-appharbor) to make the NuGet package work as part of you AppHarbor build.

Comment: Package Restore is how I am using NUnit with AppHarbor.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you added reference to NUnit, which is installed on your development PC (path points to NUnit installation folder: `Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.9\bin\net-2.0\framework\nunit.framework.dll`). There are two options to fix this:

- Install NUnit on PC where you running tests
- Use a reference to local `nunit.framework.dll` in your tests project

I prefer second one.

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah I do have reference to NUNIT framework in the Program files... When I submit my code (w/o the nunit framework binary) to github, appharbor starts building the latest code which is on their servers. That's all great.   I was wondering if I still needed to do the second option (which i prefer as well)... i thought since appharbor supported the NUNIT version, it may figure out to put the binary appropriately without me needing to include it. Doesn't seem to be the case though.